# resource ids in eclipse not shown

Tags: android, eclipse

My eclipse is not showing me IDs of resources. In XML it appears with no error but in .java it does not. I have cleaned the project, I refreshed it but it still does not appear.

I am talking about the findViewById (R.id.       );

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should have imported the wrong R class, make sure that you not imported the native R android class. And every update in your XML should be saved to be avaliable in your R class

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove this line- `import android.R;' from your activity will solve your Problem.

Comment: thank, but the only thing that worked was close eclipse and open again all the time that I want an ID, I have to close.

Comment: i think this should work...after making changes first save your xml, now clean your project...give this a try

Comment: @user2446251 mark your question as answered buddy.